# Make [download] a synonym of [downloads] and merge the two tags

Tags: support, status-completed, tag-synonyms, retag-request

There are

- 73 questions tagged [download](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/download)
- 69 questions tagged [downloads](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/downloads)

The two tags are redundant, please consider making [download](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/download) a synonym of [downloads](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/downloads) and merge the 2 tags (note:[downloads](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/downloads) has tag wiki, so having this as a master would be nice)

Also, consider merging [download-speed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/download-speed) with [download](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/download) - though a synonym isn't necessarily needed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All done, I looked through and it made sense. Thanks for bringing this up.